# Applescript open tall image zoom 100% and print to pdf

Tags: automation, applescript

hello im still new to apple script heres my try

```
 /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari & sleep 1 && osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to open location "file:///Users/user/Documents/tall.png"'
```

missing part is how to **zoom in** the tall png and **print into pdf** so a tall image could be something like

[image]

not

[image]